# Map multiple ForeignKeys to one entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

Im designing database that contains two entitites. `Match` and `Team`.

```
public class Match
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int TeamOneId { get; set; }
        
    public int TeamTwoId { get; set; }
}

public class Team
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public List<Match> Matches { get; set; }
}
```

As you can see, `Team` can be mapped as `TeamOne` or `TeamTwo`.

I want to map `Matches` to `Team` depends on `TeamOneId` and `TeamTwoId` from `Match` entitity on the same time.

I make model builder:

```
public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Team> builder)
        {
            
            builder.HasKey(x => x.Id);

            builder
                .HasMany(x => x.Matches)
                .WithOne()
                .HasForeignKey(x => x.TeamOneId)
                .HasPrincipalKey(x => x.Id);
            
            builder
                .HasMany(x => x.Matches)
                .WithOne()
                .HasForeignKey(x => x.TeamTwoId)
                .HasPrincipalKey(x => x.Id);
        }

// matches

builder.ToTable("Matches");
            
builder.HasKey(x => x.Id);
builder.Property(x => x.TeamOneId).IsRequired();
builder.Property(x => x.TeamTwoId).IsRequired();
builder.Property(x => x.MatchDate).IsRequired();
```

But as i can see, EF cant map it properly:

[image]

Is it possible to map two FK from one table to another entity in database?

Answer (score 0):

I would take this approach, this of course is psudo code but this should help you get on your way.

```
builder.Entity<UserActivity>(x => x.HasKey(ua =>
    new { ua.AppUserId, ua.ActivityId })); /// <-- this defines a concatenated key

builder.Entity<UserActivity>()
    .HasOne(u => u.AppUser)                /// <-- this says that the UserActivity has One AppUser
    .WithMany(a => a.UserActivities)       /// <-- to many User Activities
    .HasForeignKey(u => u.AppUserId);      /// <-- with this Foreign Key - App User Id

builder.Entity<UserActivity>()             
    .HasOne(a => a.Activity)               /// <-- this says that the UserActivity has One AppUser
    .WithMany(u => u.UserActivities)       /// <-- to many User Activitiesthis Foreign Key
    .HasForeignKey(a => a.ActivityId);     /// <-- with this Foreign Key - Activity Id
```

Comment: Could you reproduce your answer to my scenerio?

Comment: The code that you have given are those your full entities?

Comment: Yup, feel free to use it. Maybe two lists in `Team` entity (maybe `TeamTwoMatches`, `TeamOneMatches` will be better approach?)